# please help with my "shuffle" code in ruby

Tags: ruby, shuffle

this is the question

> Shuffle. Now that you’ve finished your
>   new sorting algorithm, how about the
>   opposite? Write a shuffle method that
>   takes an array and returns a totally
>   shuffled version. As always, you’ll
>   want to test it, but testing this one
>   is trickier: How can you test to make
>   sure you are getting a perfect
>   shuffle? What would you even say a
>   perfect shuffle would be? Now test for
>   it.

This is my code answer:

```
def shuffle arr
    x = arr.length
while x != 0
        new_arr = []
    rand_arr = (rand(x))
    x--
    new_arr.push rand_arr
    arr.pop rand_arr
end

new_arr

end

puts (shuffle ([1,2,3]))
```

What are my mistakes? Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Why have you put `rand(x)` in parentheses?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Bad answer, no answer, error messages?

Comment: homework? interview screening?

Comment: rand.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Comment: rand(x) this is meaninig - ran(arr.length)- for the clean

Comment: The least you could do is posting valid code that runs...

Comment: Yes, but why did you put parentheses outside of `rand(x)` - i.e. why did you write `(rand(x))`? What were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside minor other errors you seems not to understand what pop and push are doing (taking or adding some items from the end of the array).

You are probably trying to write something like below.

```
def shuffle arr
    x = arr.length
    new_arr = []
    while x != 0
        randpos = rand(x)
        x = x-1
        item = arr[randpos]
        new_arr.push item
        arr[randpos] = arr[x]
        arr.pop
    end

    new_arr

end

puts (shuffle ([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a far more Rubyish version:

```
class Array
  def shuffle!
    size.downto(1) { |n| push delete_at(rand(n)) }
    self
  end
end

puts [1,2,3].shuffle!
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more concise way of writing it:

```
def shuffle(arr)
  new_arr = []

  while (arr.any?) do 
    new_arr << arr.delete_at(rand(arr.length))
  end

  new_arr
end
```

And some tests:

```
5.times do
  puts shuffle((1..5).to_a).join(',')
end

>> 4,2,1,3,5
>> 3,2,1,4,5
>> 4,2,5,1,3
>> 5,2,1,4,3
>> 4,3,1,5,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your indexes mixed up with your values. When you do `new_arr.push rand_arr`, you're putting whatever random index you came up with as a value on the end of `new_arr`. What you meant to do is `new_arr.push arr[rand_arr]`, where `arr[rand_arr]` is the value at the index `rand_arr` in `arr`.

Comment: the eror is: rand.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        new_arr.push arr[rand_arr] the code is:def shuffle arr
 x = arr.length
while x != 0
        new_arr = []
 rand_arr = (rand(x))
 x--
 new_arr.push arr[rand_arr]
 arr.pop arr[rand_arr]
end

new_arr

end

puts (shuffle ([1,2,3]))

Comment: this one is the compilation error, just replace x-- by x = x - 1 will fix it. But that is not enough to make code works, there is also logical errors.

Comment: @gal I suggest you learn Ruby before trying to go any further with this.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html, look at the part on decrement and increment

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 have a built-in Array#shuffle method.

Comment: yes, but the OP needed to write it as some sort of an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Mark Thomas's answer. His algorithm can be quite slow with a large array, due to delete operation performance.

```
class Array
  def shuffle!
    size.downto(1) do |n|
       index=rand(n)
       # swap elements at index and the end
       self[index], self[size-1] = self[size-1],self[index]
    end
    self
  end
end

puts [1,2,3].shuffle!
```

This algorithm is O(size), while Mark's algorithm is O(size^2). On my computer, Mark's answer takes 400 seconds to shuffle an array of 1,000,000 elements on my machine, versus 0.5 seconds with my method.